# How to access a specific element of an array in MikroC

Tags: arrays, c, mikroc

I have this array in MikroC:

```
         char array[4] = {'1','1','0','\0'};
```

I'm trying to get a specific element in this array and outputting it on a GLCD, let's say the first element. How can I do it? I know it should be something like that:

```
         Glcd_Write_Text(array[0], 5, 4, 2);
```

but this gives no output at all or maybe some random garbage. Hence, I tried working with pointers as follows:

```
         Glcd_Write_Text(&array[0], 5, 4, 2);
```

but it gives the whole array and I need the first element only.
I tried that too:

```
                      int *v=&array[0];
                      char y=*v;
```

but outputting y gives random garbage data.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The name `Glcd_Write_Text` sounds like it expects the first argument to be a string, not a single character. Do you have a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Glcd_Write_Text` expects the argument to be a string, you can't give it a pointer to a single character. It expects a pointer to a null-terminated string.

Declare a new array and copy the specific element to its first character.

```
char text[2] = {'\0', '\0'};
text[0] = array[0];
Glcd_Write_Text(text, 5, 4, 2);
```